# Can we use a user defined function with some parameters, multiple times in a python program?

Tags: python, function, ssl, user-defined-functions

I want to send mail for different cases in my python program, but my 'message' (check program) in each case is different, how do I solve this ?
I want to send mail with different messages each time using the same user defined function, that is, sendmail(mail,message)

```
def sendmail(mail,message):
    port = 587  # For starttls
    smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
    sender_email = "something@gmail.com"
    receiver_email = mail
    password = 'password123'

    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
        server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
        server.starttls(context=context)
        server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

---

```
message = f"""\         #my first message
  Subject: Use OTP {no} Dear {extname(am1)}, 
  Use OTP {no} to access your account. 
  Don't share it with someone else. """ 
  sendmail(mail,message) 

  message = f'''\         #my second message
  Subject: ZABANK: Current Balance 
  Dear {extname(am1)}, 
  Your current balance is {extbal(am1)} rupees. ''' 
  sendmail(mail,message)
```

I ended  up getting my first message twice.
Here, mail is not required as it is a variable assigned to another user-defined function.

Comment: Show us the code where you call sendmail

Comment: You can use a list to store your messages

Comment: You say "I want to send mail with different messages each time using the same user defined function, that is, sendmail(mail,message". Call the user-defined function multiple times, each time passing a different value for the second parameter (message).

Comment: @Martheen It's in the question itself.

Comment: Any difficulty in calling the user-defined function multiple times (with a different second argument each time)?

Comment: @AvenDesta Can you give me an example...

My 1st message is
message = f"""\
Subject: Use OTP {no}
Dear {extname(am1)},
Use OTP {no} to access your account.
Don't share it with someone else.

"""

My second message is 
message = f'''\
                    Subject: ZABANK: Current Balance
                    Dear {extname(am1)},
                    Your current balance is {extbal(am1)} rupees.
                    '''

Can you show me with above messages?

Comment: @Martheen
1)

message = f"""\
Subject: Use OTP {no}
Dear {extname(am1)},
Use OTP {no} to access your account.
Don't share it with someone else.

"""
sendmail(mail,message)



2)

message = f'''\
                    Subject: ZABANK: Current Balance
                    Dear {extname(am1)},
                    Your current balance is {extbal(am1)} rupees.
                    '''
                sendmail(mail,message)
                

Here, mail is not required as it is a variable assigned to another user-defined function.

Comment: @fountainhead I'm getting the same former message twice

Comment: Don't put it into the comment, update your question instead. If you encounter an error, include them in your question

Comment: @fountainhead 
Example: My first message should be, "Hey" and my second message should be "Hello".
But I'm getting "Hey" message twice in my mail .

Comment: @Martheen Okay, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot recall the function twice as it will require two simultaneous SMTP logins,
that is logging into your account when you are already logged in(hence the 2nd msg is not sent). you can overcome this by iterating over a list of your messages

```
#please change your funtion name to avoid collision with the smtp.SMTP.sendmail method 
def usersendmail(mail,message):
    port = 587  # For starttls
    smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
    sender_email = "something@gmail.com"
    receiver_email = mail
    password = 'password123'

    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
        server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
        server.starttls(context=context)
        server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        for msg in messagelist:
            server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, msg)

usersendmail("them@gmail.com",["mymessage1","mymessage2"])
```